# Convert every PDF in the current directory to PNG

Tags: bash, imagemagick

I want to write a Bash script to convert every `.pdf` file
in the current directory into a `.png` file.

For example:

```
$ls .
a.pdf b.pdf

$./pdf2png.sh
Converting pdfs to pngs
a.pdf -> a.png
b.pdf -> b.png
```

This is my best attempt:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
convert -verbose -density 500 -resize '800' a.pdf a.png
convert -verbose -density 500 -resize '800' b.pdf b.png
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you have *really* strange names, ones that contain newlines or backslashes and the like, you could do something like this:

```
find . -type f -name '*.pdf' -print0 |
  while IFS= read -r -d '' file
    do convert -verbose -density 500 -resize 800 "${file}" "${file%.*}.png"
  done
```

That should be able to deal with just about anything you throw at it.

Tricks used:

- `find ... -print0` : causes `find` to print its results separated by the null character, let's us deal with newlines.
- `IFS=` :  this will disable word splitting, needed to deal with white space.
- `read -r`: disables interpreting of backslash escape characters, to deal with files that contain backslashes.
- `read -d ''`: sets the record delimiter to the null character, to deal with find's output and correctly handle file names with newline characters.
- `${file%.*}.png` : uses the shell's inbuilt [string manipulation abilities](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) to remove the extension.

Comment: Both answers are good but I accepted this one because it comes with an explanation of the tricks used.

Comment: Or do it portably (POSIX) and still handle any special characters: `find . -type f -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c 'for f do convert -verbose -density 500 -resize 800 "$f" "${f%.pdf}.png"; done' find-sh {} +`  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/321753/135943 for explanation and background.

Comment: @Wildcard the only non-posix thing here is find's `-printf`, so all you'd need for portability is to replace it with ` -exec printf '%s\0' {} +`.

Answer (score 17):

You can use bash `for` loop as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
for pdfile in *.pdf ; do
  convert -verbose -density 500 -resize '800' "${pdfile}" "${pdfile%.*}".png
done
```

Answer (score 9):

You could use `mogrify` to batch convert & resize all `.pdf`s in the current directory:

```sh
mogrify -verbose -density 500 -resize 800 -format png ./*.pdf
```

When using a different `format` (in this case `-format png`) the original `.pdf`s are left untouched, the output files having the same name except for the extension which will be changed to the one specified by `format`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not restricted to using bash, then you could use a python script to convert all of the `.pdf` files in the current directory to high-resolution `.png` images. It could be modified for other input/output image types, or to use different arguments for `convert`.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import os

def main():
    dir_list = os.listdir('.')
    for full_file_name in dir_list:
        base_name, extension = os.path.splitext(full_file_name)
        if extension == '.pdf': # then .pdf file --> convert to image!
            cmd_str = ' '.join(['convert',
                                '-density 400',
                                full_file_name,
                                base_name + '.png'])
            print(cmd_str)  # echo command to terminal
            os.system(cmd_str)  # execute command

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```